# 2 ways of raising a button event

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to understand the difference between the two ways of calling a button event.  Here are the 2 examples:

```
$('body').on('click', '#myButton', function () {
```

or

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function () {
```

I noticed that some examples on the web use the 1st and others use the 2nd.

Should I be using one or the other or are they interchangeable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version is a *delegate*, http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ while the other version is a *regular* event handler

The main difference is that the *delegate* version of on will be able to handle elements that was created dynamically. Regular eventhandlers can only be used with elements that are available on the DOM directly after page load.